# Background image for minipage

Tags: graphics, minipage, backgrounds

I'd like to put a background image into a minipage, stretching exactly to the surrounding fbox. What's the best option to do that? (Searching the web, I only found solutions for backgrounding the whole page)

Comment: AFAIK the `tabu` package does something like this for table cells. Maybe it can be used otherwise as well or you can create a 1-cell table as workaround.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You basically need to store the `minipage` content in a box register, measure it and overlay it with the graphic. The following environment awaits the image file name as first argument and then accepts any `minipage` arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\mysavebox
\newenvironment{imgminipage}[2][]{%
   \def\imgcmd{\includegraphics[width=\wd\mysavebox,height=\dimexpr\ht\mysavebox+\dp\mysavebox\relax,#1]{#2}}%
   \begin{lrbox}{\mysavebox}%
   \begin{minipage}%
}{%
   \end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}%
   \sbox\mysavebox{\fbox{\usebox\mysavebox}}%
   \mbox{\rlap{\raisebox{-\dp\mysavebox}{\imgcmd}}\usebox\mysavebox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{imgminipage}{imagefilename}{5cm}
    Some text\\
    Hello world!
\end{imgminipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

I added now a `bgimage` key to `adjustbox` (develop version) which allows you to add a background image. To have also a `\fbox` use either:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=<width>,fbox,bgimage=<image>}
    <text>
\end{adjustbox}
```

which adds the `\fbox` first and then places the background image behind it, so that the frame covers some small part of the image, or

```
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=<width>,margin=\fboxsep,bgimage=<image>,frame}
    <text>
\end{adjustbox}
```

which adds the same margin manually, places the background image and then draws a tight frame around it, so that the image is fully shown (and a little bit smaller than before).

Comment: In case somebody stumbles over the same problem when applying this: `minipage` uses zero `parskip` by default. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/how-to-preserve-the-same-parskip-in-minipage) for a workaround. (And thanks for the `adjustbox` solution; you created a great package there!)

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newsavebox\MBox
\newenvironment{Minipage}[1]
  {\par\smallskip\begin{lrbox}{\MBox}\begin{minipage}{#1}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
   \makebox(0,0){\put(0,0){%
     \includegraphics[width=\wd\MBox,height=2\ht\MBox]{tiger}}}%
   \usebox\MBox\par%
  }
\begin{document}
Some text before

\begin{Minipage}{0.5\textwidth} 
\blindtext
\end{Minipage}

Some text behind    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:**

Here a modification of the package `mdframed`. So you can use all the settings which are provided by `mdframed` according to the background image:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backgroundcolor=yellow!10,style=0]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*\mdf@backgroundimage{%
      \rlap{\hspace*{0.5\mdfboundingboxwidth}%
             \makebox[0pt][c]{%
               \tikz[remember picture]%
                  \node (0,0) [opacity=0.4] {%
                  \includegraphics[width=\mdfboundingboxwidth,%
                                height=\mdfboundingboxheight,%
                                keepaspectratio]%
                                {\backgroundimage}%
                              };
             }%
           }%
}
\newenvironment{Minipage}[2][]
  {\def\backgroundimage{#2}%
   \appto\md@frame@background@single\mdf@backgroundimage%
   \appto\md@frame@background@first\mdf@backgroundimage%
   \appto\md@frame@background@middle\mdf@backgroundimage%
   \appto\md@frame@background@second\mdf@backgroundimage%
   \begin{mdframed}[#1]%
   }
  {\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Some text before

\begin{Minipage}{tiger} 
\blindtext
\end{Minipage}

Some text behind    

\begin{Minipage}{tiger} 
\blindtext[10]
\end{Minipage}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2** Thanks to xport -- I added the option `opacity` by using `tikz`.

[image]

A possibility is to combine `minipage` with `includegraphics`. I tried it with the following configuration (option `demo` and `color{red}`. So I can compile without any image :-)

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\widthofminipage}
\newsavebox{\MyMinBackBox}
% minipageback{<width>}{<backgroundimage>}
\newenvironment{minipageback}[2]{%
      \setlength{\widthofminipage}{#1}%
      \def\pictureminback{#2}%
      \begin{lrbox}{\MyMinBackBox}%
      \begin{minipage}[b]{\widthofminipage}\color{red}%
    }{%
     \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
     \includegraphics[width=\wd\MyMinBackBox,height=\dimexpr\ht\MyMinBackBox+\dp\MyMinBackBox\relax]{\pictureminback}%
    \llap{\usebox{\MyMinBackBox}}%
}

\begin{document}
Text 


\begin{minipageback}{.5\textwidth}{logo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipageback}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\includegraphics` also supports `width` and `height` keys, so you don't need to use `adjustbox` for the resizing. I actually just today uploaded the new version of `adjustbox` which has now a `minipage` key which can be used to collect and frame the text content. I might actually add support for a background image later :-)

Comment: @Martin: I saw the update. :-). I changed the code - thanks

Comment: @Macro: Any I put the background image to my TODO list for the next version of `adjustbox`. :-)

Comment: @Martin: I am thinking about an extension for `mdframed` too :-)

Comment: @Martin: I modified it :-)

Comment: @xport: You are right. I have to implement an opacity-parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This shows a solution with `tcolorbox`. `blankest` skin doesn't draws any frame or changes margins, so text formatting is similar to `minipage`. But `tcolorbox` offers `watermark text|graphics` options to introduce a background text or image behind box contents. This watermark can be forced to use the whole box with option `watermark stretch=1` which won't keep image aspect ratio. If aspect ratio must be conserved, `watermark zoom=1` will enlarge image to maximum width or height but without distorting image proportions.

Ah! With `breakable` option, it's possible to break `minipages` across pages and repeat the image behind every fragment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{myminipage}[3][]{
    breakable,
    blankest, 
    watermark graphics=#3, 
    watermark stretch=1,
    width=#2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myminipage}{\linewidth}{example-image}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myminipage}

\begin{myminipage}{.5\linewidth}{example-image}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myminipage}

\begin{myminipage}{.75\linewidth}{example-image}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{myminipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Features:** The opacity can be adjusted such that it does not distract the foreground texts.

Compile the following with either `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\newsavebox\IBox
\newenvironment{TinyPage}[2][1]
    {\def\scale{#1}\begin{lrbox}{\IBox}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#2\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}\ignorespaces}
    {%
        \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%              
        \rput(\dimexpr0.5\wd\IBox+\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,0){%
                \special{ps: 0.2 .setopacityalpha}%
                \scalebox{\scale}[1]{\includegraphics[width=\wd\IBox]{Images/hen}}%
                \special{ps: 1 .setopacityalpha}}%
        {\color{gray}\fbox{\usebox\IBox}}%
        \ignorespacesafterend}

\parindent=0pt
\fboxsep=10pt
\fboxrule=10pt
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{3mm}

\begin{TinyPage}[-1]{0.49}
\lipsum[1]
\end{TinyPage}\hfill
\begin{TinyPage}{0.49}
\lipsum[1]
\end{TinyPage}

\vspace{3mm}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use cocks for examples, if you do not mind me asking?

Comment: Excuse my mistake, then. It looked like a cock to me. So why do you use hens? I am interested.

Comment: @xport: With the using of `\fbox` you should modify the length-parameter of `minipage`. When you use `\begin{TinyPage}[\linewidth]` the frame is to big. You can use something like this:
`\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}`

Comment: @HaroldCavendish What do you have against hens? I am interested.

Comment: @cfr Wow, that was quite a while ago. :D I have nothing against cocks or hens, I was just curious because xport used to feature them everywhere, even in his/her profile picture, so there was obviously some significance. In fact, I was equally interested in xport who, as far as I remember, was very good at PSTricks, TikZ, etc., had become a major contributor to the site, and then suddenly disappeared without a trace.

Comment: @HaroldCavendish Makes sense. I was just curious. Can't help with the xport mystery, I'm afraid. Probably you need Dirk Gently for that :-).