# Making a checkered background for a page

Tags: backgrounds

I am writing a math work, and I'd like to create a background which looks like a math notebook. Any idea how to do it ?

I found this solution, but I don't know how to put it in a mini-page ...

```
%%%
%%% quarre Kaestchenmuster
%%%
\def\quarre{%
\raisebox{\footskip}[0pt][0pt]{%

setlength{\unitlength}{.01\textwidth}% Einheit_1/100_Textweite
\begin{picture}(100,115)%
\color{black!10}%
\linethickness{0.075mm}%
\multiput(2,0)(2,0){49}{\line(0,1){110}}% 110-VER
\multiput(0,2)(0,2){54}{\line(1,0){100}}% 54-HOR
\color{black}%
\put(1,112.1){%
\begin{footnotesize}
\textsl{\textbf{Notizen}}
\end{footnotesize}}%
\end{picture}%
}%
}
```

would be great to combine it with this:
[Background image for minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25614/background-image-for-minipage)

Comment: The background must be for the whole page or just for the text area?

Comment: for the text area, and also, how can i put it in a mini-page ?

Comment: For the text area, change `\paperwith` and `\paperheight` to `\textwidth` and `\textheight`, respectively, in my example. For a `minipage`, another approach will be needed, but you can use PGF/TikZ in that case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using the `background` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\paperwidth/40\relax}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{blue!30}
\SetBgContents{\tikz{\draw[step=\mylen] (-.5\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight) grid (.5\paperwidth,.5\paperheight);}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's an adaptation for TikZ of the code found here, for the case of `minipage`s; the main environment is `gridmp` with an optional argument (the color for the rules) and a mandatory argument (the  width of the `minipage`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\MyGrid[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[step=3mm,color=#1] (0,0) grid (#3,#2);
    \draw[color=#1] (0,#2) --  (#3,#2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newlength\MaxHt
\newsavebox\mybox

\newenvironment{gridmp}[2][lightgray]
  {\def\mycolor{#1}
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
      \begin{minipage}{#2}}
  {\end{minipage}%
   \end{lrbox}%
   \setlength\MaxHt{\dp\mybox}\addtolength\MaxHt{1.1\ht\mybox}
   \noindent%
   \raisebox{-\dp\mybox}{\MyGrid{\mycolor}{\MaxHt}{\wd\mybox}}%
   \usebox{\mybox}
   \vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gridmp}{\linewidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{gridmp}

\begin{gridmp}[blue!30]{\linewidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{gridmp}

\begin{gridmp}[green!30]{\linewidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{gridmp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is great, but i need to break my head how to make it work on debian squeeze, i am missing some latex packages (pause.sty, background.sty)...

Comment: @Oz123 You can get `background.dtx` and `background.ins` from CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/background. Run `latex background.ins` to generate the `.sty` file that you can now place somewhere TeX can find it (your current working directory, for example). However, `background` uses `PGF/TikZ`, so if your system also lacks this package (or uses an old version), the problem will persists. Did you install your LaTeX system from the Debian repos? If so, it would be better to uninstall it and install TeX Live 2011 from TUG: http://www.tug.org/texlive/.

Comment: Hmm... I appreciate your hint, but I rather not mess around with texlive. It might break other codes I need. So, I'll wait for debian. Can I somehow combine my partial solution with that link ???

Comment: @Oz123: waiting for Debian repositories to get an updated LaTeX system could mean waiting for years (they still use TeX Live2009!). Anyway, download `background.dtx` and `background.ins` and proceed as I say in my previous comment, and keep your fingers crossed ;-)

Comment: I found this solution http://tug.org/PSTricks/Grids/overlay0.tex, but it won't compile , telling me "Undefined Control Sequence \end{dogrid}... any idea why?

Comment: @Oz123: since it uses PS-Tricks, you can't compile using pdflatex; you have to use latex. or xelatex.

Comment: thanks, it does work. In parallel I also found a solution in a German website. I still wonder how to put a tikz picture in the background of a mini-page. But for now it's good enough.

Comment: @Oz123: I'm designing a basic solution for `minipage`s. However, I won't be able to post it right now. In 24 hours (or less, but I don't promise) I will update my answer.

Comment: @Oz123: I finally had time and designed and posted the solution for `minipage`s; it should work with your current LaTeX installation.

Comment: thanks, this seems much nicer than the simple solution I found.

Answer (score 4):

From a German website a nice solution which does work with the old tex-live.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\karos}[2]{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (#1 cm ,#2 cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \karos{15}{4} % Karos der Breite 15cm und Höhe 4cm
\end{minipage}

%mini page ohne 
\karos{8}{3} % Karos der Breite 8cm und Höhe 3cm
\end{document}
```