# Problem with TikZ in highlighting parts of a formula

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to write the formula in the picture and I have a problem in highlighting the term **q** and the term **m**. unfortunately I can not manage the piece of code that helps me to look for the formulas. Can you help me?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
           \draw[thick,blue,fill=blue!20,rounded corners] 
               ($(pic cs:mark1)+(-1,-4pt)$) -- ($(pic cs:mark1)+(0,10pt)$) -- 
               ($(pic cs:mark2)+(2pt,10pt)$) -- ($(pic cs:mark2)+(1pt,+3pt)$) -- 
               ($(pic cs:mark4)+(2pt,6pt)$) -- ($(pic cs:mark4)+(2pt,-7pt)$) -- 
               ($(pic cs:mark3)+(-1,-4pt)$) -- ($(pic cs:mark3)+(0,8pt)$) -- cycle; 
           \draw[blue,thick,-latex] ($(pic cs:mark2)+(2pt,4pt)$) to [in=180,out=15] +(30:1cm) 
               node[anchor=west,text=black] {angular coefficient};
       \end{tikzpicture}
       \begin{equation*}
          y={m\tikzmark{mark1}\tikzmark{mark2}\tikzmark{mark3}\tikzmark{mark4}} \cdot x +q
       \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why have you placed four `\tikzmark`s in the same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another approach

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
         y = \tikz[baseline=(n1.base)]{\node[fill=yellow!50, draw, circle,  inner sep=1.5pt] (n1){$m$};
         \node[overlay, above right=of n1] (t1) {angular coefficient};
         \draw [->] (n1.north) to [bend left=45] (t1.west);
         } 
         \hspace{-1cm}\cdot x +\tikz[baseline=(n2.base)]{\node[fill=green!50, draw, circle, anchor=south, inner sep=1.5pt] (n2){$q$};
         \node[overlay, below right=of n2] (t2) {$y$-intercept};
         \draw [->] (n2.south) to [bend right=45] (t2.west);
         }
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The background grid can be drawn according with @GonzaloMedinas's answer [Making a checkered background for a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37222/125434)

Comment: @ryuk I tried to be the more accurate possible according to your orginal question. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: To get rid of the manual `\hspace{}`, you should add the `overlay` option to the two `\draw[->]` commands.

Comment: @hbaderts Excellent! I noticed that you used it in your answer. There are many many features of `TikZ` that I do not know. Thank you for the tip, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `\tikz{}` command directly inside `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` to create the letters "a" and "q". That way you don't even need `\tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        y =
        \tikz[baseline=(a.base)]{
            \node[circle, draw=blue, fill=blue!60, inner sep=1pt] (a) {$a$};
            \draw[overlay, blue, thick, -latex] (a.north) to[out=90, in=180] +(30:1cm)
                node[anchor=west,text=black] {angular coefficient};
        }
        \cdot x +
        \tikz[baseline=(q.base)]{
            \node[circle, draw=green, fill=green!60, inner sep=1pt] (q) {$q$};
            \draw[overlay, green, thick, -latex] (a.south) to[out=-90, in=180] +(-30:1cm)
                node[anchor=west,text=black] {y-intercept};
        }
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting equation]

Answer (score 9):

Think of a `\tikzmark` as an invisible character that doesn't take up any space. In your code you placed four of those *in the same place*.

It makes more sense I think, to place a mark on either side of the character you want to highlight, i.e. `\tikzmark{mark1} m \tikzmark{mark2}`. To draw  rectangle around the `m` you can then do something like

```
\draw[thick,blue,fill=blue!20,rounded corners] 
           ($(pic cs:mark1)+(-1pt,-4pt)$) rectangle ($(pic cs:mark2)+(1pt,10pt)$);
```

The first coordinate is below left of `mark1` (which is on the left side of `m`), the second coordinate is the opposite corner, above right of `mark2` (which is on the right side of `m`).

That said though, it might be just as easy to use a `\node` to draw the rectangle, then the annotation arrow can be drawn directly from the node. Use the `fit` library, and `\node [fit=(pic cs:mark1)(pic cs:mark2),minimum height=3ex,...]` to make a node that encompasses the two `\tikzmark`s.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%           \draw[thick,blue,fill=blue!20,rounded corners] 
%               ($(pic cs:mark1)+(-1pt,-4pt)$) rectangle ($(pic cs:mark2)+(1pt,10pt)$);
%           \draw[thick,blue,fill=red!20,rounded corners] 
%               ($(pic cs:mark3)+(-1pt,-4pt)$) rectangle ($(pic cs:mark4)+(1pt,10pt)$);
%           \draw[blue,thick,-latex] ($(pic cs:mark2)+(2pt,4pt)$) to [in=180,out=15] +(30:1cm) 
%               node[anchor=west,text=black] {angular coefficient};

 \node [fit=(pic cs:mark1)(pic cs:mark2),inner sep=2pt,minimum height=3ex,yshift=0.5ex,blue!20,draw,thick,rounded corners] (a) {};
 \node [fit=(pic cs:mark3)(pic cs:mark4),inner sep=2pt,minimum height=3ex,yshift=0.5ex,red!20,draw,thick,rounded corners] (b) {};

 \draw [-latex] (a) to[bend left] ++(2,1) node[right] {angular coefficient};
 \draw [-latex] (b) to[bend right] ++(1,-1) node[right] {$y$-intercept};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{equation*}
          y=\tikzmark{mark1}m\tikzmark{mark2} \cdot x + \tikzmark{mark3}q\tikzmark{mark4}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```