# How to preserve the same parskip in minipage

Tags: spacing, minipage, lengths, parskip

I have following structure:

```
\begin{document}

Paragraph1.
Paragraph2.

\begin{minipage}
Some paragraph1.
Some paragraph2.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the same spacing between paraghs in minipage section as in plain paragraphs?
Would like to make it as macros, in order not to repeat it many times, but this failed:

```
\let\currentparskip\parskip
\newenvironment{minipage_parskip}{
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}
  }
}{
  \end{minipage}
}
```

Comment: Elaborate on what "failed" means. Also note that you're using an underscore in your environment definition which would not be allowed. Finally, your use of length setting is only local since you're surrounding it by group braces, so the effect is only momentary.

Comment: @Werner Why should the underscore be disallowed?

Comment: @egreg: I notice now that it is defined via `\csname`...`\endcsname` and since one never (or rarely) use `\<env>`...`\end<env>` it is "allowed", I guess.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`\parskip` is the name of the length parameter that contains the current value of the parskip; so `\let\currentparskip=\parskip` and `\setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}` is equivalent to `\setlength{\parskip}{\parskip}` and inside a minipage does nothing, as the value of `\parskip` is already zero.

```
\newlength{\currentparskip}
\newenvironment{minipageparskip}
  {\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% open the minipage
   \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value
  }
  {\end{minipage}}
```

While an underscore in the name of an environment is not forbidden, it's better not to use it, as some packages do change its meaning and may break your environment.

Answer (score 31):

Both `\parbox` and `\begin{minipage}` temporarily reset `\parindent=0pt` and `\parskip=0pt` (and a few other parameters), which can be a nuisance.

Fortunately, `\begin{minipage}` also executes the `\@minipagerestore` macro after this, which is a hook to allow a LaTeX style to override these defaults. (See the ltboxes section in "texdoc source2e".)

So just try something like

```
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\newcommand{\@minipagerestore}{\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}}
```

in your style or class file.

Changing the behaviour of the existing "minipage" environment has the advantage that this will automatically affect the many other environments that use minipage internally (such as "columns" in beamer).

Comment: This works like a charm when added to the preamble. Just had to put `\newcommand{\@minipagerestore}{\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}}` inside `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: Markus, do you know of a list of the parameters reset by a minipage?  I found [the unofficial reference](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html#minipage), but it only mentions `\parindent`.  **Edit** per your comment on `source2e`, is it the `@arrayparboxrestore` list?  That appears to be `parindent parskip everypar leftskip rightskip parfillskip lineskip lineskiplimit baselineskip`