# Put quote in new page if it does not fit

Tags: page-breaking, quoting

I have a `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` which I would not like to be broken in separate pages. So  if it's at the end of a page and there's not enough space, it would go into a new page automatically. Is it possible to achieve this? I've looked around and found no clues up to now.

Obviously, I'm not after the `\newpage` solution. I'd like something automated.

Comment: Usually `quote` is for short quotations (one or more), whereas `quotation` is for longer ones. You can look at the `quoting` package for customizing the appearance of quotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the quote in a `{minipage}`, so it won’t break across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% some blind text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{quote}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{minipage}
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Note that the `{minipage}` must be inside of `{quote}` and that the environment has an mandatory argument that specifies the width of the `{minipage}`, in this case it should be `\linewidth`. And please see [locksteps answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97754/4918) about the *`\parskip` drawback*.

Answer (score 3):

Tobi's solution has one minor drawback: The `minipage` environment features a `\parskip` of 0pt, so paragraph breaks in a `quote` environment using a `minipage` may go unnoticed. Remedy: save the value of `\parskip` within `quote`, but before starting the `minipage`, and restore it within the `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% some blind text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{quote}
    \edef\normalparskip{\the\parskip}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parskip}{\normalparskip}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{minipage}
\end{quote}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related References: [How to preserve the same parskip in minipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/how-to-preserve-the-same-parskip-in-minipage) and [Why is \parskip zero inside a minipage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/why-is-parskip-zero-inside-a-minipage).

Comment: Is it the same with `\parindent`?

Comment: @Tobi Yes, but `minipage`'s `\parindent` matches `quote`'s.