# mdframed box, cross-reference, paragraph spacing

Tags: cross-referencing, mdframed, parskip

I'm trying to create an environment that provides a framed box within a report. My current problems are:

1. The interparagraph spacing does not match the body text spacing (the space within the box is small)
2. The box caption prints but can't be cross-referenced (the labels aren't getting through)

---

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,twocolumn,landscape]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption,mdframed,newfloat,xcolor}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries\color{orange}}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.75\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}


\definecolor{orangeBackground}{RGB}{254,240,222}
\DeclareCaptionFont{orange}{\color{orange}}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Box]{smallboxfloat}
\mdfdefinestyle{aFrameBox}{%
    linecolor=orange,
    nobreak=true, % prevents page breaking
    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=11pt,
    innerleftmargin=11pt,
    backgroundcolor=orangeBackground
    }

\newenvironment{smallbox}[2]{%
\begin{smallboxfloat}
\begin{mdframed}[style=aFrameBox]%
 \captionsetup{labelfont={bf,orange}, font={bf,orange}, format=plain,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
 \caption{#1}\label{#2}
}{\end{mdframed}\end{smallboxfloat}}   

\begin{document}
 \begin{smallbox}{Box title}{box:label}
  \lipsum[1-2]
 \end{smallbox}
 \subsection{Title}
 \lipsum[1-2] \Vref{box:label}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe, that `varioref` and `cleveref` are not getting well with each other.  I think `cleveref` itself is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that familiar with `cleveref` but think what you need is

```
\crefname{smallboxfloat}{Box}{Boxes}
\Crefname{smallboxfloat}{Box}{Boxes}
```

so that `cleveref` knows how to refer to the `smallbox` environment.

The paragraph spacing is due to the fact that `mdframed` uses a `minipage` which sets `\parskip` to zero.  This can be fixed by saving the value of `\parskip` before the `smallboxfloat` environment:

```
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
```

and then restoring it once  you are in the `smallboxfloat` environment:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}
```

### References:

- [Why is \parskip zero inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64982/why-is-parskip-zero-inside-a-minipage)
- [How to preserve the same parskip in minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/how-to-preserve-the-same-parskip-in-minipage)

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,twocolumn,landscape]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption,mdframed,newfloat,xcolor}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries\color{orange}}
\crefname{smallboxfloat}{Box}{Boxes}
\Crefname{smallboxfloat}{Box}{Boxes}
%\RedeclareSectionCommand[
%  beforeskip=-.75\baselineskip,
%  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}





\definecolor{orangeBackground}{RGB}{254,240,222}
\DeclareCaptionFont{orange}{\color{orange}}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Box]{smallboxfloat}
\crefalias{⟨counter ⟩}{⟨type ⟩}
\mdfdefinestyle{aFrameBox}{%
    linecolor=orange,
    nobreak=true, % prevents page breaking
    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=11pt,
    innerleftmargin=11pt,
    backgroundcolor=orangeBackground
    }

\newlength{\currentparskip}%
\newenvironment{smallbox}[2]{%
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value
\begin{smallboxfloat}
\begin{mdframed}[style=aFrameBox]%
\setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value
 \captionsetup{labelfont={bf,orange}, font={bf,orange}, format=plain,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
 \caption{#1}\label{#2}
}{\end{mdframed}\end{smallboxfloat}}   

\begin{document}
 \begin{smallbox}{Box title}{box:label}
  \lipsum[1-2]
 \end{smallbox}
 \subsection{Title}
 \lipsum[1-2] \Vref{box:label}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the symbols in the argument for `\crefalias`?

Comment: @Hugh: That should be a separate question if it is not clear from the documentation. That way it can be helpful to more people as an answer for that is unlikely to be able to be easily located if it is buried in an answer regarding `mdframed`.