# Minipage reset indent. How can i set again to standard?

Tags: formatting, indentation, minipage

I have the following code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, 11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduzione all'astrofisica}  
   \begin{minipage}{12cm}
    In astrofisica, differentemente da altre scienze, non \`e possibile 
    eseguire degli esperimenti diretti sugli oggetti di studio. 

   L'assenza di questi viene colmata grazie all'\textit{osservazione 
   degli astri}, tramite telescopi e, nello specifico, tramite 
   l'osservazione della \textit{posizione} dei corpi celesti e della
   \textit{luce} da loro emessa.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

What I want is a regular indentation, like a document without minipage. How can I get that?

Thank you.

Comment: The MWE from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271490/compute-depth-of-paragraph does this and more.

Comment: exploring the link you gave me, i found the solution to my problem.

just use this:
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\@minipagerestore}{\setlength{\parindent}{XXpt}}

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, 11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduzione all'astrofisica}  
\edef\myindent{\the\parindent}% store parindent value
   \begin{minipage}{12cm}\setlength{\parindent}{\myindent}
    In astrofisica, differentemente da altre scienze, non \`e possibile 
    eseguire degli esperimenti diretti sugli oggetti di studio. 

   L'assenza di questi viene colmata grazie all'\textit{osservazione 
   degli astri}, tramite telescopi e, nello specifico, tramite 
   l'osservazione della \textit{posizione} dei corpi celesti e della
   \textit{luce} da loro emessa.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

**Update** for `\parskip` one can use `\edef\myparskip{\the\parskip}` and `\setlength{\parskip}{\myparskip}`

There is no way to do this at one but you can do it like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, 11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\saveparinfos}{%
\edef\myindent{\the\parindent}%
\edef\myparskip{\the\parskip}}

\newcommand{\useparinfo}{%
\setlength{\parindent}{\myindent}%
\setlength{\parskip}{\myparskip}}

\begin{document}
   L'assenza di questi viene colmata grazie all'\textit{osservazione 
   degli astri}, tramite telescopi e, nello specifico, tramite 
   l'osservazione della \textit{posizione} dei corpi celesti e della
   \textit{luce} da loro emessa.

   L'assenza di questi viene colmata grazie all'\textit{osservazione 
   degli astri}, tramite telescopi e, nello specifico, tramite 
   l'osservazione della \textit{posizione} dei corpi celesti e della
   \textit{luce} da loro emessa.
\section{Introduzione all'astrofisica}  
\saveparinfos
   \begin{minipage}{12cm}\useparinfo
    In astrofisica, differentemente da altre scienze, non \`e possibile 
    eseguire degli esperimenti diretti sugli oggetti di studio. 

   L'assenza di questi viene colmata grazie all'\textit{osservazione 
   degli astri}, tramite telescopi e, nello specifico, tramite 
   l'osservazione della \textit{posizione} dei corpi celesti e della
   \textit{luce} da loro emessa.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for this! Do you know if there's a way to set either indentation and spacing? i know that with \setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount} i can set the spacing and with \setlength{\parindent}{\myindent} i can set the indent, but how can i use them together? And what's the equivalent of \edef\myindent{\the\parindent} for spacing? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: you have to add `\edef\myparskip{\the\parskip}` and `\setlength{\parskip}{\myparskip}`

Answer (score 3):

Thank to everyone, by your help and some research i finally got the answer.

I used:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\@minipagerestore}{
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}}
\makeatother
```

This seems to work.