# Have document's \parskip in minipage

Tags: indentation, minipage, environment-variables, parindent

I embed an illustration of variables next to the paragraph describing them:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
    \indent Lorem ipsum
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    …
\end{tikxpicture}
```

You can already see my use of `\noindent` to avoid the whole textblock being indented. Then I try to explicitely indent the text in the minipage (I still need the first line indentation, like in any other paragraph).

I learned that minipage sets `\parindent` to 0pt. How can I set it to the value used in the rest of the document? (I would like to avoid setting a specific value that might fit or might not fit the template.)

Comment: please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303018/minipage-reset-indent-how-can-i-set-again-to-standard/303025#303025

Comment: I had read that question, but it didn't cover how to read the current setting (\the\parskip in that case).