# Minipage of width \textwidth is not as wide as other text

Tags: minipage

In my mastersthesis, I have a lot of equations I am deriving. I want to avoid situations where we have something 'introducing' a set of equations on the end of one page, such as

> "The results (1.4) and (1.6) allow us to write Maxwell’s equations in
>   the way they are most commonly presented in literature:"

and then on the next page have the actual equations. Hence, I did some research and found that the often suggested way to do this was to wrap the two in a `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`.

However, I tried this, yet I found the the width is the same width as that of a line introducing a new paragraph, instead of the full line width. See image below:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

The results \eqref{eq:max4} and \eqref{eq:max6} allow us to write Mawell's equations in the way they are most commonly presented in literature:

\begin{align*} 
\nabla \times \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t}  \tag{\ref{eq:max1}}\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}, t) + \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t} \tag{\ref{eq:max2}}\\
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= \rho(\mathbf{r}, t) \tag{\ref{eq:max6}} \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= 0 \tag{\ref{eq:max4}}
\end{align*}

Deriving the equations this way shows that the four equations above are not independent - using the physical propperty of conservation of charge, \eqref{eq:max4} and \eqref{eq:max6} are derived from \eqref{eq:max2} and \eqref{eq:max1} respectively.

\end{minipage}

The equations derived up to now are all in the time domain. However, it is generally more convenient for the applications at hand to work in the frequency domain.
```

Which yields this on my page:

[image]

Where you can see that the text in the minipage is not as wide as normal text, but is the same width as the indented line at a new paragraph.

I am using a custom thesis template provided by my faculty. I won't post the entire thing (for now). However, if it turns out this is not just me misunderstanding the way different functions work, and is due to the template I will see how I can add it (since it requires custom installations)

Comment: Add a `\noindent` command just before `\begin{minipage}`

Comment: @koleygr yes, that did fix it. It seems so obvious now I think about it. Is there anyway to still indent the text normally? As is, it does not indent anything right now, but I would like to keep the indenting of the first line as in the remainder of the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title is not really true. It is not wider but shifted to the right by `\parindent`.

LaTeX started a paragraph at the begin of your command and so the whole minipage moved to the right.

You can avoid this "indent" by using the command `\noindent` just before the paragraph/minipage start.

For the comment's question you can use the way discribed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303025/120578

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\parindent{15pt}
\setlength\parskip{10pt}

\begin{document}
\edef\myindent{\the\parindent}%
\edef\myparskip{\the\parskip}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\setlength\parindent{\myindent}
\setlength\parskip{\myparskip}

The results \eqref{eq:max4} and \eqref{eq:max6} allow us to write Mawell's equations in the way they are most commonly presented in literature:

\begin{align*} 
\nabla \times \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t}  \tag{\ref{eq:max1}}\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}, t) + \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}(\mathbf{r}, t)}{\partial t} \tag{\ref{eq:max2}}\\
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= \rho(\mathbf{r}, t) \tag{\ref{eq:max6}} \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, t) &= 0 \tag{\ref{eq:max4}}
\end{align*}

Deriving the equations this way shows that the four equations above are not independent - using the physical propperty of conservation of charge, \eqref{eq:max4} and \eqref{eq:max6} are derived from \eqref{eq:max2} and \eqref{eq:max1} respectively.

\end{minipage}

The equations derived up to now are all in the time domain. However, it is generally more convenient for the applications at hand to work in the frequency domain.

\end{document}
```