# Putting a lstlisting in a minipage breaks xleftmargin settings

Tags: listings, indentation, minipage

I want to display a listing in a gray box with some space around the sides.
I've set up `\lstset` the way I like it:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\bfseries
,commentstyle=\itshape\color{green},
xleftmargin=\parindent,  <<--- minipage breaks this setting.
backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
framexleftmargin=\parindent,
framextopmargin=6pt,
framexbottommargin=6pt, 
frame=tb, framerule=0pt}
```

I don't want page breaks in short listings. I fix this using a minipage. However this breaks my margin settings.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}[Scale=0.85]
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,64,0}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\bfseries,commentstyle=\itshape    \color{darkgreen}, xleftmargin=\parindent,backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
framexleftmargin=\parindent,
framextopmargin=6pt,
framexbottommargin=6pt, 
frame=tb, framerule=0pt}
\begin{document}
\section{listing}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[H]{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Delphi,caption={get the next block},label={ref:bitset_next},
                   keywords={function,int,asm,end},xleftmargin=\parindent]
function bitset.next(previous_block_index: int): int;
//***************************************************************************
//pseudo code:
//***************************************************************************
//Load the bitset into a register
//shift out the bits that we've already processed
//count the number of inactive blocks
//next_block_index = previous_block_index + inactive_blocks_inbetween + 1
asm
  //rcx = self = pointer to bitset
  //edx = previous_block_index
  mov rax,[rcx]            //rax = bitset.
  lea ecx,[edx+1]          //go to the next bit    
  shr rax,cl               //shift out the bits we've already processed
  tzcnt rax,rax            //count empty positions to skip
  add eax,ecx              //return (prev+1+empty positions found)
end;  
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

If I remove the `\noindent` and the `minipage` it looks like this.

[image]

Which has the correct indentation inside the listing. 
How do I get the listing to not have a page break inside, but keep the correct spacing inside the gray box.

I've tried

```
\begin{lstlisting}[float,floatplacement=H]
```

But that produces the same output as the `minipage` above.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\parindent` is set to zero in a minipage.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @egreg. I found the answer here: [How to preserve the same parskip in minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/how-to-preserve-the-same-parskip-in-minipage)

Simply copy pasting the above linked answer will yield a gray background that extends beyond the rest of the text, so some adjustments are needed.

The fix is to define a new -fixed- length that will replace the variable `\parindent` inside the `minipage`.

The following change fixes the issue:

```
\newlength{\listingindent}                %declare a new length
\setlength{\listingindent}{\parindent}    %make it a fixed version of \parindent
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\bfseries,commentstyle=\itshape\color{darkgreen},backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
xleftmargin=\listingindent,         <<-- make fixed 
framexleftmargin=\listingindent,    <<-- make fixed
framextopmargin=6pt,
framexbottommargin=6pt, 
frame=tlrb, framerule=0pt,linewidth=\linewidth}
....
\noindent      <<-- force noident, or the frame will appear out of bounds
\begin{minipage}[H]{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Delphi,caption={get the next block},label={ref:bitset_next},
                   keywords={function,int,asm,end}]
function bitset.next(previous_block_index: int): int;
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

No page breaks in the middle of a listing and no misaligned background.