# Background image in mdframed left top

Tags: graphics, xetex, mdframed

I want use picture in frame as watermark. `mdframed` was used as this [How can I insert a background image in mdframed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383883/how-can-i-insert-a-background-image-in-mdframed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If the picture is centered, as indicated in the example, everything is ok, but if I move it to the left border, the frame itself slides.
I also noticed that the **\scoped** command is used, but I could not find its description.

Second, as I understand it, option backgroundcolor not works when using a picture for the background. Is there any way to set a light gray color for the background of the frame besides the picture?

**Screenshot**

[image: Frame moved righth]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 11pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[left=20mm,right=10mm,top=17mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
                   %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}


% -------------- Настраваем шрифты -----------------------------
\input{fonts.tex}


% --------------- Формат для оглавлений ------------------------
\titleformat
    {\chapter} % command
    [display]  % shape
    {\Huge\bfseries} % format
    {
    \raggedleft
    {
        \fyanone\bfseries\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont Часть
            \chn\fontsize{64pt}{20pt}\selectfont\thechapter}
    } % label
    {-6pt} % sep
    {
        \titlerule[2.5pt]
        \vspace{1.2pt}
        \titlerule[1.2pt]
    } % before-code

\titleformat{\section}[display]
    {\Large\sffamily}
    {}{}{\uppercase}
  [
    \vspace{-12pt}%
    \rule{36mm}{0.5pt}
    \vspace{4pt}
  ] %

\titleformat{\subsection}[wrap]
{\bfseries\sffamily}
{}{}{}[]

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{8pc}{1.5ex}{1pc}


%------------------- Содержание ---------------------------
\titlecontents{chapter}
[2.5em]
{\addvspace{20pt}\filcenter}
{\Large\MakeUppercase{часть\ \thecontentslabel}\ \sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
{}
[\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\hspace*{8pt}]

\titlecontents{section}
[0pt]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{}
{\normalsize\sffamily\uppercase}
{\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
[25pt]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{}
{\sffamily\bfseries}
{\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}

% ---------------- Счетчики ------------------------
\newcounter{qenum}
\newcounter{q1}


\newcommand{\qa}{\addtocounter{q1}{1}\arabic{q1})\ }

\newenvironment{quest}{%
 \setcounter{qenum}{0}
 \sffamily
 \vspace{12pt}
 \centerline{\textbf{Вопросы для размышления:}}
 \vspace*{-6pt}
 \centerline{\rule{120pt}{0.5pt}}
 \vspace*{-12pt}
 \small
 \begin{enumerate} \leftskip=0.5em \rightskip=0.5em \parskip-1em \itemsep=1.3em \parsep=0em
 \item[]}
 {\end{enumerate}}


%-------------- Настройка стиля mdframed для цитат-------------------
\mdfdefinestyle{bible}{
  backgroundcolor=black!15,
  linecolor=black!25,
  leftmargin=4mm,
  rightmargin=0,
  innerrightmargin=2mm,
  innerleftmargin=20mm,
  roundcorner=8pt,
%   apptotikzsetting={%
%     \tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={},}
%   },
  singleextra={%
    \scoped[on background layer]{\node [xshift=.2*\mdfboundingboxwidth, yshift=.7*\mdfboundingboxheight, opacity=0.4] 
    % {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{prijatelj.jpg}};
     {jdkjasdiqwuie};
    }
  },
}



%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%               Create a new command
%               /bquute  цитата из Библии
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\bquote}[1]{
  \begin{mdframed}[style=bible]
 {\bibquf\footnotesize\textit„{#1}“}
  \end{mdframed}
 }


% ---------------- Основная информация книги ----------------------



% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
\sloppy %------------------------------ Красивое формирование строк|
\parindent=18pt %------------------------------Отступ первой строки|
\setlength{\columnsep}{14pt} %------------Растояние между колонками|
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.05pt} %----------Линия между колонками|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|
%\tolerance=600
%\emergencystretch=2pt
\hfuzz=0.9pt
\doublehyphendemerits=9000000
% ---------------- Двухколоночное формирование текста -------------
\twocolumn
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\hyphenpenalty=800
\righthyphenmin=2

\makeatletter
\def\qitem{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \qitem@}
\bgroup\catcode`\^^M=12 %
   \gdef\qitem@#1^^M{\addtocounter{qenum}{1}\item[\textbf{В.\arabic{qenum}:}] #1?\endgroup}%
\egroup
\makeatother

\linespread{0.93}

\ULdepth = 0.2em

%==================================================================
%                                                                 |
%                   BEGIN OF DOCUMENT                             |
%                                                                 |      
%==================================================================

\begin{document}
\author{Юхименко Игорь}
\title{Закон и Благодать}

\begin{titlepage}
\makeatletter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering{\huge\sffamily\@author} \par
\vspace*{100mm}
\centering{\fontsize{48pt}{66pt}\selectfont\itshape\@title}
\makeatother
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% ================ Подключаем нужные файлы ========================
% \input{вступление.tex}





Это всё, что мы можем узнать о Терахе из Библии. Дальше фокус
повествования смещается на его сына Аврама, которому в Харране явился
Бог\footnote{Это было первое явления Бога Авраму, о котором сказано в
Библии} со словами: \bquote {Оставь отчий дом и родных и иди в землю,
которую Я укажу тебе, ибо произведу от тебя многочисленный народ, и ты
станешь благословением для всех народов земли. Кто тебя благословит, того
Я благословлю, кто тебя проклянет — того Я прокляну.} \par

% =================================================================

% ---------------- Содержание книги -------------------------------
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Содержание}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\onecolumn
{При подготовке данного издания была использована технология \XeLaTeX}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, do you colud add a complete MWE and no a snippet (fragment) code?

Comment: @Sebastiano, I have edited it. I think I understood the reason. This happened because the picture climbs out of the frame.