# How do I add a background image to just a parbox?

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, parbox, layout

I'm trying to design my CV and want to have a box at the top which contains some content on the left end (name and title) and content on the right (maybe a few rows containing contact info sorts of stuff).  Currently I'm thinking of structuring that in parboxes and tabular environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin={.5cm,.5cm},vmargin={.2cm,0cm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  % To contain the top bar:
  \parbox{\paperwidth}{
    % To contain the left side:
    \parbox{12cm}{
      % Name title stuff
    }
    % To contain the right side:
    \parbox{4cm}{
      \begin{tabular}{r}
        % rows of info
      \end{tabular}
    }
  }
  % To contain the rest of the document:
  \parbox{\paperwidth}{
    % The rest goes here
  }
\end{document}
```

I would like the top parbox to have a light transparent image behind it.

[Edit: More specifically I have an image that is, let's say, 1300px wide by 1000px tall (could change in the future).  I would like the background image to fill the height of the top bar (parbox).  So I want it to be the minimum of: The image height, 1000px, and the parbox height (which I suppose I could fix at 3cm or so).  I want the width of the image to be whatever width maintains the aspect ratio of the original image.  I also want the image centered in the top bar (parbox).]

Is there a way to accomplish this?  Most of the similar solutions I've found put the image either in the upper-left or center of the image and not attached to an environment inside the page.  Perhaps rather than attaching the image to the parbox I should just use `eso-pic` to just locate and scale the image manually?

I've only just started laying this out so if anyone has suggestions about restructuring how I control the layout, I'm open.

I've found this solution which I've tried adapting to my situation: [Background image for minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25614/background-image-for-minipage)

However, I don't want the image to fill the surrounding box since the image is too small to scale nicely to that given size. I want the image to fill the height of the box and keep the aspect ratio (i.e. automatically scale the width so that the image renders as nicely as possible).  I tried setting the height and width information manually but it just ended up rendering the picture outside of the minipage.

I also tried the answer on that page using `mdframed` but for whatever reason the image didn't render at all in that solution.  The solution with `tcolorbox` renders but again the image is scaled too much.  Would it be best if I just editted the image to make it wider and get around the scaling issue that way?

Comment: it is quite unclear what scaling and size you actually want.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've added an edit to hopefully make this clearer.

Comment: One solution is to use tikz [remember picture,overlay] and another is to use everypage.